# how to wait css3 animated frame for few seconds and reload it?

Tags: css, css-animations

am doing with  CSS3 animate one after another with delay for radio buttons. here i wanted to do like load 10 radio buttons one after one in 2 seconds and then stay for 3 seconds, and then again load 10 buttons. here i was successful up to first 2 seconds but not second 3 seconds waiting time. This is [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/mssjdb/DT6Xu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

do not quite understand what you mean, but that's what I understood.

but check this out if you want

http://jsfiddle.net/DT6Xu/8/

```
@-webkit-keyframes FadeInOut { 
  0% {opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(.1);}
  25% {opacity:1; -webkit-transform:scale(1.05);}
  50% {-webkit-transform:scale(1); opacity:1}
  74% {-webkit-transform:scale(1);opacity:1 }
  75% { -webkit-transform:scale(1); opacity:1}
  100% {opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(.1);}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. am searching for this only. if i wanted to load images from left to right(not like fadeinout) then what i have to do ? give me an idea.